# Jquery Animation behavior

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

Say that i have 4 divs that i want to animate.

1st div shows a fish, 2nd div shows a box, 3rd fish shows a locker and the 4th div shows the top of the box. What i have achieved thus far is to animate my div as follows:

The fish goes from right to left until it comes to the same vertical level with the box, then the fish is animated towards the box, the box top closes and the locker appears. The animations proceeds as i scroll with my mouse.

This is my code:

```
var fish_animation = $(".fish-animation");
var boxtop_animation = $(".boxtop-animation");
var locker_animation = $(".locker-animation");

if(height == 100){ 
    fish_animation.css({ right:'120px'}, { duration: 100, easing: 'easeInSine'});
}                       
else if (height == 200) { 
    fish_animation.css({right:'230px'}, { duration: 100, easing: 'easeInSine'});
}
else if (height == 300) { 
    fish_animation.css({right:'340px'}, { duration: 100, easing: 'easeInSine'});
}
else if (height == 400) { 
    fish_animation.css({right:'450px'}, { duration: 100, easing: 'easeInSine'});
}
else if (height == 500) { 
    fish_animation.css({right:'560px'}, { duration: 100, easing: 'easeInSine'});
}  
else if (height == 600) { 
    fish_animation.css({top:'270px'},   { duration: 400, easing: 'easeInSine'});
}
else if (height == 700) { 
    fish_animation.hide();
    fish_animation.removeClass('fish-graphic-blue');
    fish_animation.addClass('fish-graphic-white');
    fish_animation.fadeIn('normal');
    fish_animation.css({ 'zIndex' : '1000' });
}
else if (height == 800) { 
    boxtop_animation.css({'top' : '-10px', 'right' : '-233px'});
    boxtop_animation.rotate({animateTo:-90}); 
}
else if (height == 900) { 
    kleidaria_animation.fadeIn('fast'); 
}
```

When i start scrolling from the top of the page to bottom everything goes as intended. But here is my problem. Say that i refresh while i have already scrolled up to the point of 700px. Then my animation is messed up. The steps are shown in incorrect order. I am unsure what to do or how to proceed to solve this. Anyone has any suggestions?

Thank you so much

Comment: Is this code triggered by an event? Perhaps by `$(window).scroll(function() {` ??

Comment: On page loading you can check current `height` value and perform all required actions at once (maybe even without animation).